# Stopping uninstall method,when user interrupts uninstall

Tags: c#, custom-action

I have a setup project in Visual Studio 2008, and I am struggling with setting up custom actions. In install method,I create shortcut on desktop and startMenu according to the user's selection,in unintall method,I delete them.
My problem is when user interrupts uninstall(at uninstall form click the [Cancel] button),my shortcut still was deleted.How can I stop it?

Here is my code:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class InstallarEx : Installer
{
  public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
  {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
        DeleteShortcuts();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Rollback custom action should work for this. Rollback applies to uninstall rollback as well as install rollback. The difficulty might be determining that an uninstall rollback is in progress from a VS setup with limited support for some functionality.

First, if the install fails, you need a rollback to delete the shortcuts, so you need a rollback custom action that has a condition of Not Installed - it can check for and delete the shortcuts. The Installed property won't be set because the profuct install failed, that's why "Not Installed" will call the CA to delete the shortcuts.

If the uninstall fails and rolls back, you need a rollback custom action that creates the shortcuts again, so use a condition of Installed. The product is still installed if the uninstall fails, so a condition of Installed means that the your CA should be called to create the shortcuts.

That may be worth a try - the changes seem minor and should work.